# How can I create customized buttons in Adobe Campaign?

Tags: forms, button, adobe

We are creating the following form in Adobe Campaign using its Web Form builder.

How can we create these two customized buttons (one says, "Medical Professional," the other, "Patient") with Web Form builder in Adobe Campaign?:

[image]

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Jae

Answer (score 0):

[Adobe forum](https://forums.adobe.com/thread/2334083) already provided answers this question.
Solution:
"Please have a look at the following documentation about Personalizing form rendering. What you need to do is add the fields/buttons that you need and override the default CSS with your stylesheet or specifications.
There have been some other posts related to CSS in web applications on this forum so don't hesitate to browse through it."

Alternatively, if you are using Page(Vesrsion 5), then you can just duplicate existing button. Refer to the screenshot attached.

If you are still confused or looking for more details, please feel free to ask.

Hope this helps,
Regards,
Amit.

Answer (score 0):

Considering you already know how to write CSS, you can easily style buttons for adobe campaign forms either by writing attributes for the class used by the button in the stylesheet (Template). To find out which template is used you can go to form properties > Rendering and find out the name of the template. See attached images.
[image]

Once you know the template name you can navigate to administration>configuration>form rendering to add CSS there. 

Or you can go to the form header by navigating inside the "page activity" and click on "header" and write the appropriate CSS. In this case, you may need to override existing attributes. Refer to the image.

[image]

If you need more help, feel free to ask.

Kind regards,
Imran